# Как запускать gif по клику или при наведении?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gif

Помогите пожалуйста сделать на моём сайте wordpress (https://giffs.ru), так,  чтобы гифки запускались по клику или наведению. Сам я новичок в скриптах не разбираюсь пока, а все плагины GIF Animation Preview и WP GIF Player не срабатывают, уже неделю бьюсь. В идеале хотелось бы что то на подобии http://fishki.net/auto/2413484-podborka-avtomobilynyh-gifok.html как тут!

Comment: Вам надо обратиться в фрилансеру, который сделает это вам за деньги. Либо учиться и пробовать, если что-то не получается, то вам тут помогут.

Comment: `//первоначально показываете статическую картинку, а не gif


// берем основной блок с картинками


var div = document.getElementById("div");


//отслеживаем клик по картинке


div.onclick = function(event){
 var target = event.target;


 //заменяем картинку на гифку
 target.src = "путь к гифке";
};`


Я вижу это так

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, как вы добавляете gif в свой пост?
[WPGP gif_id=»147″ width=»1200″] так? Попробуйте так как указано в readme на гитхабе: [WPGP gif_id="147" width="600"]

Comment: Я так пробую и в этом случае тоже к сожалению, превью картинка не создаётся((( https://giffs.ru/123-2/

Comment: только надпись GIF и всё(((

Answer (score 3):

Ну, например, вот так

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("img").hover(function() {
    var src = this.src;
    this.src = $(this).data("img");
    $(this).data("img", src);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DBNBnMLsnrs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/onFqjfb9JQs/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" data-img="http://liubavyshka.ru/_ph/177/2/403146738.gif"/>
<img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-A58yPmvdnIc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2o1tCSQHEG0/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" data-img="http://lizasimpson.com/uploads/_pages/613/simpsons-avatars-2.gif"/>
<img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-sEESfUOW2IM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/7E_dHNhe9wI/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" data-img="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/1/17/Simpsons-1.gif/revision/latest?cb=20081006234733"/>
```

На попадание/убегания мыши меняем местами значения атрибутов `src` и `data-img`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что этот код нужно добавить в functions.php и после этого подобная вставка должна давать такой эффект?

Comment: @Евгений к сожалению, с WordPress не знаком. Пробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Сначала показывайте неанимированную картинку а при наведении заменяйте на гифку.

Comment: Ну я это понимаю, но я же говорю, что новичок, можно как то поподробнее мне объяснить как это реализовать? А схему то я понимаю....

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/210807)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в приницпе, это ответ.